# email_otp package does not function as it used to

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a flutter project and I'm using email_otp package to send a verification code to the email

```
myAuth.setConfig(
        appEmail: "example@gmail.com",// used a real email but for email hiding purpose I put this
        appName: "Spectrum Speak",
        userEmail: _emailController.text,
        otpLength: 4,
        otpType: OTPType.digitsOnly,
      );
      bool r = await myAuth.sendOTP();
      if (r == true) {
        print("done send");
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('OTP has been sent'),
          ),
        );
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => OTPScreen(
              myAuth: myAuth,
              email: _emailController.text,
              comeFromSignUp: true,
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        print("error");
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Oops, OTP send failed'),
          ),
        );
      }
```

So it always returns a false valuem even though it was functioning properly two weeks ago

I have the latest version of email_otp in `pubscpec.yaml`, it's supposed to return a `true` value and send the OTP to the email in the `_emailController.text`
I'd appreciate it if someone would tell me if they faced this and how did they fix it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Update: Gave up on this package and used a third party api called EmailJS to send OTP verification

```
Random random = Random();
// Generate a random number between 0 and 9999
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(10000);
// Format the number to have leading zeros if needed
String formattedNumber =randomNumber.toString().padLeft(4, '0');
try {
     final url = Uri.parse("https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send");
     final response = await http.post(url,
                            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                            body: jsonEncode({
                            'service_id': 'spectrumspeak',
                            'template_id': 'spectrumspeaktemplate',
                            'user_id': 'OBNbTFzznmRQQuw3G',
                            'template_params': {
                              'user_name': _userNameController.text,
                              'otp_code': formattedNumber,
                              'user_email': _emailController.text
                            }
                          }));
                      print("done send");
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(
                          content: Text('OTP has been sent'),
                        ),
                      );
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => OTPScreen(
                            otpCode: formattedNumber,
                            email: _emailController.text,
                            comeFromSignUp: false,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    } catch (e) {
                      print("error $e");
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Oops, OTP send failed'),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
```

Watch this video for more details [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HW3MZ_tsdo). Make sure to turn on the 'Allow EmailJS API for non-browser applications.' from the security section in the account tab in Email JS, also you can use API public key for the user_id

Update 2: Contacted the developer on gitbut through issues and the problem was fixed